# Recording Audio From Web Page

Tags: asp.net, flash, silverlight, audio-recording

I'm looking for a solution for capturing audio from a user's microphone and posting it (preferably as MP3) to a server.  I need something that I can embed in a web page.

I've seen where Flash can do this, but I understand that this approach requires expensive server-side software from Adobe.  I'm not aware of whether Silverlight may provide any capabilities to assist with this.

I'm curious what others have done.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with Flash and either [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5) or [haXeVideo](http://www.haxevideo.com/) or the server, both Open Source. Regarding offering a final MP3 to the user, you will need something else because these 2 tools only record to FLV format due to the licenses needed to encode MP3s. You can use something on the server such as [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for the transformation, but still, read the small print regarding MP3s.

Good luck

Juan

Comment: Thanks.  That's about what I expected, but I'm glad to have some confirmation.

Comment: Would it be possible to use just the Flash component without the server component and just save the audio file on the server?

(I ask this because I've found it difficult and complicated to install things on a server.

Comment: Hi Clay,

I don't think you can, no. If the Flash app were running as a desktop app (ie, inside an AIR app or similar) you could do it using haXeVideo locally and then posting to a server, but if the app runs inside the browser I think it's not possible.

Best

Answer (score 5):

SilverLight 4 now has the ability to record audio.  http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Audio-recorder-Silverlight-4-sample.aspx shows encoding PCM to WAV

Answer (score 4):

Silverlight does not have this capability, currently (or in their upcoming 3.0 release).  Flash would be the way to go.