# Suggestions for Web Development of a service that records & plays back sound

Tags: jquery, web-services

We are considering a web version of some of our Windows desktop software.  One of the challenges I've faced is that we need to **record sound** from the microphone for some of the programs.

Any suggestions of what options might fullfill that? (Adobe Air, Flash, Silverlight, etc.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this thread: [Recording Audio From Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911008/recording-audio-from-web-page)

There's a couple recommendations on what to use.